# How to count how many instances of a React component are mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an `Ad` component that is dynamically loaded into different pages across an eCommerce application. I'd like to be able to know how many of these components exist in a react page at any given time.

I'm wondering if there's a react pattern for determining how many instances of a component exist in a page at any given time.

I'd imagine you would do this in the root of the application, and iterate through `react.children`, counting the `Ad` components as they appear.

Does anyone know best practice for this approach?

Thanks :)

```
  match({ routes, location, history: browserHistory }, (error, renderProps) => {


    const requireComponents = (props) => props ? props.components.map((component) =>
      component && component.requireComponent && store.dispatch(component.requireComponent())
    ) : [];

    const render = () => {
      store.initialRender = true;
      ReactDOM.hydrate(
        (
          <AnalyticsProvider onEvent={analyticsHandler}>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>
            </Provider>
          </AnalyticsProvider>
        ),
        document.querySelector(".js-content")
      );
      store.initialRender = false;
    };

    Promise.all(requireComponents(renderProps))
      .then(render)
      .then(() => window.newrelic.addPageAction("FIT"));
  });
```

I've tried console.logging `renderProps` - and there are some routes in that object, and also a getComponent function but I haven't seen the results I"m looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To count the number of mounted intances of a given component, you can add the following to your component (`Ad.js` in your case).

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

let instancesCount = 0

const Ad = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    instancesCount += 1
    console.log({instancesCount})
    return () => {
      instancesCount -= 1
      console.log({instancesCount})
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    // Whatever your component does
  )
```

This will increment `instancesCount` each time a instance of `Ad` is mounted to the DOM, and decrement it each time an instance is unmounted, effectively giving you the exact number of mounted instances at any given time. It will also log that number every time an instance is mounted or unmounted.

Requirement: React v > 16.8.0

If you have a lower version of React, or if your `Ad` component is a class component, use this:

```
let instancesCount = 0
class Ad extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    instancesCount += 1
    console.log({instancesCount})
  }
  componentWillUnmount = () => { 
    instancesCount -= 1
    console.log({instancesCount})
  }

  // Whatever your component does
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I was not familiar with useEffect(). We are on react 16.8 so I'll give that a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is just use the `DOM` to locate a common class on the component. You don't have to use the `React API`.
So, if the component you are looking for has:

```
<div class="unique-component">
 ... rest of component
</div>
```

Just use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".unique-component").length
```