# In React what's the best way to render a Component differently the first time it appears on the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have some React Components that are going to be used a lot all over my App.

I'd like that only the first time they get printed in the DOM, they return as

`<symbol id="SVGComponent"><SVGComponent></symbol><use href="#SVGComponent" />`

while every other following printing should be only
`<use href="#SVGComponent" />` since the symbol has already been declared in the page

```
const [firstTime, setFirstTime] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => { setFirstTime(false) }, []);
```

```
if (firstTime) {
    return (<symbol id="Component"><Path /></symbol>);
}
else {
    return(<use href="#Component"/>);
}
```

This is my code so far but the condition always return `false`.

How is that possibile in React with `useEffect`?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I didn't understand your question. But as you say - "What's the best way to ...". Can you show us the normal / bad way of doing it i.e. the way you are doing currently?

Comment: Updated the question with my code, thanks for the help

Comment: It is half clear now. What exactly do you mean by "first time"? Here is component cycle - 1. Mounts 2. Rerenders 3. Rerenders ..... So on, Last Step - Unmounted. Which step number is first time? Is it 1st I. E. mounted one? Maybe you can better explain by showing us a complete but minimal example of the question.

Comment: I mean: very first instance of its output on the page when you inspect the page. I want it to be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up replying to myself again for anyone coming. Fortunately what I want to achieve is possibile with just a few lines of code. Thanks this guy for the code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331421/3937587

```
let instancesCount = 0
function Component(props) {
        const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(false)
        useEffect(() => {
            setFirstRender(instancesCount === 0)
            instancesCount++
            return () => { instancesCount-- }
        }, [])

        if (firstRender)
           //do something only the first time the component appears

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not that your condition always returns `false`. The issue is that you change the state immediately after your first render(in the `useEffect` where you set the state variable value to `false`) which causes another immediate rerender so you skip the `true` condition of the variable(you technically don't skip it, you just render the `true` state and rerender with `false` straight away after).

If you don't change the state in the mounting `useEffect` you'll notice that the code works properly. In order to do this, though, you'll have to use `useRef` which basically enables you to create a variable that persists between rerenders but the mutation of its value doesn't cause a rerender(unlike state variables from `useState`).

I've added a button to simulate change of state or in other words - simulate a second render:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

    const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        isFirstRender.current = false;
    }, []);

    const renderRepresentation = () => {
        if (isFirstRender.current) {
            return (
                <symbol id="Component">
                    <Path />
                </symbol>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <use href="#Component" />
            );
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {renderRepresentation()}
            <button onClick={() => setButtonClicked(true)}>SIMULATE STATE CHANGE</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

And here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-water-tpp8j?file=/src/App.js) which you can try.

Comment: Thanks this is really cool, but not what I meant. What I need it to do is that when you call 
renderRepresentation() the 2nd time (for example when you render a list of these components) only the first one says (is first Render) while the elements that comes after in the dom are rendered as (is NOT first render)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. If you have a list of items and render them on the same place(thus having a common parent and you can track their state) @samuei's solution is the way to go. If you are rendering them on different unrelated places and just want the first instance ANYWHERE on the page to be special, this is not a trivial task at all.

Answer (score 2):

The component itself won't be able to tell if others of itself exist. You will need to store this information at a higher level in the application, and then tell the component via props whether it is the first instance or not.

Comment: Seems a bit complicated, wonder why that would be so difficult. I just want the component to act differently on the first time it gets printed in the page

Comment: Because each time you use the component is a new instance, fully unaware and indifferent toward any other instances of that component you may have created before. They don't share state or anything. They are completely discrete.

Comment: I see, what about taking adavantages of the key={i} that React forces us to put when rendering a list of components? I was thinking I might check if that's 0. This for sure should work for the first rendered list I think

Comment: @AndreaScanu The `key` property is not exposed and you can't access it directly from the component. Furthermore, it is not a good idea to use indexes as keys, except where you have no better choice. If your items list can be reordered or new items can be added at an arbitrary index in the list or items can be deleted, the `key` based on index will start introducing bugs.